# What network port do clients use to send outbound packets?

Tags: networking, port

I read a post on superuser.com (https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for) that answered everything except for the port that is used. When sending out data from behind a NAT router, what port does the sending device use to send to the router and what port is used by the router once it's sent out, over the internet? I know that when a server receives this packet, it uses the port it was sent by the sending device (client) to know where to send the packet back to. But, this still doesn't answer where the NAT router came up with these two (private and public) ports originally. Do NAT routers just pick random ports and play a game of peek-a-boo with it's sending ports to make it nearly impossible for hackers to use port scanners to find an opening on random nodes on the internet? Please someone put me out of my misery.

Answer (score -1):

The port stays constant across the entire spectrum unless otherwise specified.  For example,

Client sends HTTP on 80, router forwards HTTP on 80 private to 80 public.  Internet router recieve on public 80 and forwards to private 80.

The only thing that changes at the router (behind NAT) is the requesting IP Address. If I send a packet from my computer on port 80 to am internet site, the router changes the packet Source IP to its IP and then sends it across the globe.

Now, let's say we're on a home network. Here's how things work.
192.168.0.2 send request to router headed to 8.8.8.8 (google) on port 80. Packet gets to router. Router changes the SourceIP from 192.168.0.2 to its Public IP (64.5.5.5). It stores a record of this using various information such as the requesting MAC Address. Packet arrives at 8.8.8.8, which then changes the Destination IP from 8.8.8.8 to 172.0.0.5 (some internal web server at Google) and send the request to the server. When the server send a response, the same process happens in reverse.

Comment: Client sends HTTP *to* port 80 *from* a system-allocated port.

Comment: I swear I'm not trying to be difficult, when you say it remains constant, what is this port initialized to and what determines this? When I want to send something behind a NAT, I know the router ultimately assigns each node behind it a private address. Okay, so does it also assign each node a port with the address it assigns? I'm familiar with everything else you described, especially after watching this: https://youtu.be/QBqPzHEDzvo?t=5m29s. My only confusion is the origin of the first port that is used (private side) and the port the router assigns that gets sent to the server (public side).

Comment: I'm depends on the application  (or protocol) attempting to communicate.  Here's a list of common port numbers https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: I guess I was asking the question wrong somehow. Anyway, I found the answer after a couple more days of research, however, it's not the complete answer. I only learned where the source port comes from and not the destination port.
Source: https://youtu.be/l5wuJFoeVDQ?t=15m24s